# Why CSS is not working when sending HTML email?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, html-email, sendgrid

As I am using SendGrid service at heroku, I've noticed that when I send HTML based emails, the CSS has no effect, can any one tell me what could be wrong ?

I tried to send it as html.haml, html.erb, but both didn't work, although the images are viewed correctly in the sent emails.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using inline styles instead of an external stylesheet.
Like this:

```html
<div style="color:green;" id="div"></div>
```

instead of something like this:

```html
<style>
    #div {
        color:green;
    }
</style>
    
<div id="div"></div>
```

(Thanks Kelvis Miho for pointing this out)

**Edit:** I searched for @Joe's text on Google, and I realized that most of it was copied from  http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/ .

**Edit:** Joe edited his post to include the reference link.

Remember that most email clients don't support a lot of CSS, so you should mostly be using both images, and tables.

You could, for example, code a wonderful email design and then screenshot it. With tables, you could put the logo on the top in the center, the screenshoted beautiful "featured" pane on the left, the "discount" as the content in the center under the logo, ect.

Comment: @simo Gmail only supports inline styles, so it is good practice to inline all css for html email. Also, avoid divs in favor of tables.

Comment: [Rails Internal Style For Mailer Template Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173747/rails-internal-style-for-mailer-template-not-working)

Answer (score 10):

**What you CAN'T do:**

- Include a  section with styles. Apple Mail.app supports it, but Gmail and Hotmail do not, so it's a no-no. Hotmail will support a style section in the body but Gmail still doesn't.
- Link to an external stylesheet. Not many email clients support this, best to just forget it.
- Background-image / Background-position. Gmail is also the culprit on this one.
- Clear your floats. Gmail again.
- Margin. Yep, seriously, Hotmail ignores margins. Basically any CSS positioning at all doesn't work.
- Font-anything. Chances are Eudora will ignore anything you try to declare with fonts.

There are quite a few more things you should be aware of. For a great complete list of what online email services support what, check out this article at Xavier Frenette.

**What you CAN do.**

In two words, **inline styles**. It's not as awful as you might think, since we are basically developing a one-off email, inline styles are not nearly as egregious as using them on a website.

[from this site](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/)

Comment: that is why that is part of the "can't do" list.

Comment: Also add display:block to img tags.

Comment: I would do the layout with tables.

Comment: @Joe Background images do work, but not in elements (consistently). If you set it in both body tag (for Outlook) and a 100% with table (for Gmail etc), you can get a overall email background image to work across all major email clients.

Comment: Use backgrounds.cm for background images(full email or td) Works in like 99% of email clients(including all Outlooks).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use inline styles.

Comment: I've used campaignmonitor.com/templates to generate the email template, I thought they would care about the inline styles, but it seems that I will have to fix it my self, do you know a handy tool that would convert CSS to inline style ?

Comment: 1+, thanks, its strange that Google dose not support CSS at all inside HTML emails though ..

Comment: It supports it, but inline.

Comment: Campaign Monitor has a tool that auto inlines the CSS before sending through their service. This is why they always leave it in <style> tags. Personally, I just inline straight off the bat...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are putting internal style inside head tag

eg:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    ...
    ...
    </style>
</head>
```

> Note: Only inline  style and internal style (must be in head tag) supports.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

shows all css support for popular mail clients. Also it appears that for the most popular gmail-client `display:grid/flex` is not supported

Answer (score -1):

To me, the [premailer-rails](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails) gem works like a charm. You just need to add this gems to your Gemfile

```
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'premailer-rails'
```

And all your emails will include styles from the assets folder. I usually create a `email.css.less` in the assets folder and then I include it on the `<head>` of the email like this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'email.css' %>
```

And also, when I need to include an **image** I found this helper that allows me to attach images into the email so they have logo and stuff.

```
module EmailHelper
  def email_image_tag(image, **options)
    attachments[image] = File.read(Rails.root.join("public/#{image}"))
    image_tag attachments[image].url, **options
  end
end
```

And in the .erb template

```
<%= email_image_tag "img/logo.png", :class => "some-class" %>
```

Hope it helps someone, Regards