# Rails Internal Style For Mailer Template Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Internal style written in rails mailer template is not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
      ...
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
          ...
          ...
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to add more information if you want to get any kind of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why CSS is not working when sending HTML email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085630/why-css-is-not-working-when-sending-html-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are putting internal style inside head tag

eg:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    ...
    ...
    </style>
</head>
```

> Note: Only internal style (must be in head tag) supports.

Comment: remove that and edit your question, is better, this question can being downvoted.